# How to hide caret in Delphi TEdit?

Tags: delphi, textbox, caret

I want to remove the caret from a TEdit control in Delphi. I have made the component `Enabled := False` but the caret still appears. 
My question is how to remove the caret from a disabled TEdit control?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you mean `TEdit` control.

The solution is `HideCaret` function, the only problem is where to call it. The 2 event handlers below worked fine for me:

```
procedure TForm18.Edit1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  HideCaret(Edit1.Handle);
end;

procedure TForm18.Edit1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HideCaret(Edit1.Handle);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. I've found another solution for this problem. I just set ReadOnly with True.

Comment: @Jordan That does something else though doesn't it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes it does but I want to remove the caret only for make a text box read only without caret when I click it.

Comment: @user246408 thank you, it works in D7 too. But in tEdit there is no "MouseEnter", only "MouseDown". Has something changed in newer Delphi versions?

Answer (score 0):

Place a `TApplicationEvents`control on the form and in the `OnIdle` event, hide the caret, as follows. Set the event to nil so it only fires once.

```
procedure TFormMain.AppEventsIdle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
begin
  AppEvents.OnIdle := nil;
  HideCaret(Memo1.Handle);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:
Set focus on a different component after adding text.

```
// Remove caret by setting focus on a different component
btn1.SetFocus;
```