# How do I hide the caret from a TEdit in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, caret

Well, that's pretty similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659734/how-to-hide-caret-in-delphi-tedit).

But

```
HideCaret(YourAwesomeTEdit.Handle);
```

seems not to be available for `Firemonkey`. I can't figure out how to use the same function, or even something that would achieve the same effect would be nice for the `iOS` app.

How do I hide the caret from a TEdit in Firemonkey?

Comment: From a UX perspective that seems a very bad idea.

Comment: Here's how to do it in pure objective-C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699727/hide-the-cursor-of-an-uitextfield/13660503#13660503

Comment: @Johan I have a situation where the user click's "Done" at the keyboard and the caret remain blinking at the screen. From a UI perspective, it's gross not to remove it.

Comment: Then you should change the focus away from the TEdit towards the button. That should fix the issue.

Comment: I'd thought setting `.setFocus;` for another control would solve it, but it doesn't.

Comment: You need to set the focus to a control that can actually receive the focus. Don't know exactly how this works in ios.

Comment: You can change the color of the caret to the background color so you don't see it.

Comment: @Johan Obj-C not really pertinent because FMX does not use native controls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TEdit has a caret property which you can set the visible property to false.

```
edit1.caret.visible:= false;
```

I don't recommend this however in your situation, as then you need to remember to re-enable it.

Also it's not clear what you mean by the 'done button' on the keyboard. Are you running on mobile? If so, then you can simply set the `KillFocusByReturn` property to `true`, and then the caret will automatically disappear and focus shifts to the form after the keyboard closes.

Comment: Yes I'm running it on mobile. However it doesn't disappear with `KillFocusByReturn`.